# icon makes the button not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button, on which I have an absolute positioned search icon. 
the Button is working fine on the edges but not on an icon. 
The button is unclickable for the entire portion of the search icon.

[image: button with a absolute positioned icon]

code for Icon placement

```
.custom-position {
right: 32px;
position: absolute;
top: 27%;}
```

Is it possible to make the button clickable on the places where the icon is occupying space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try adding: `pointer-events: none` to your icon/image.

Example:

```
.custom-position {
  right: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

[pointer-events docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)